# Data and Series label not showing on WinForm Chart control

Tags: winforms, charts, graphics, data-visualization, microsoft-chart-controls

I am having a problem getting the default WinForms Chart control to work. I have a single chart with a single area. In this area, I want to display three (3) series whose labels are on a single legend.

Each of the value arrays shown in the code below contains six (6) values.

When I run the application the chart is only showing the background with the title and the name of the FIRST series I defined, the others seem to be ignored. Also, no grid and no data points or lines are displayed. The chart is basically blank.

[image: run-time chart]

```
this.chart.SuspendLayout();
this.chart.ChartAreas.Clear();
this.chart.Series.Clear();
ChartType chartType = ChartType.Column;

// prepare the area
const string AREA_NAME = "ChartAreaBP";
ChartArea bpChartArea = new ChartArea(AREA_NAME);
bpChartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MMM\nyyyy";
bpChartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
bpChartArea.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
bpChartArea.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
bpChartArea.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalRight;
bpChartArea.Position.Auto = true;
bpChartArea.InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;
this.chart.ChartAreas.Add(bpChartArea);

// prepare the values. X is Date/time all other 3 are BYTE/INT
var xvals = from x in items select x.TimeStamp;     
var yvalsSys = from y in items select y.Systolic;   
var yvalsDia = from y in items select y.Diastolic;  
var yvalsRhy = from y in items select y.Rhythm;

// The first series, other 2 omitted from HERE for simplicity
const string SYS_SERIES = "Systolic";
Series sysBPSeries = new Series(SYS_SERIES, 4);
sysBPSeries.ChartType = chartType;
sysBPSeries.ChartArea = AREA_NAME;
sysBPSeries.XValueType = ChartValueType.Auto;
sysBPSeries.YValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
sysBPSeries.XAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
sysBPSeries.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
sysBPSeries.Enabled = true;
this.chart.Series.Add(sysBPSeries);
this.chart.Series[SYS_SERIES].Points.DataBindXY(xvals, yvalsSys);

// here the other two series are defined.
```

But when I run the application only the legend of the FIRST series is shown even though the other two are defined in the code (I omitted them from this listing) just the same way as the first series.

And as I stated above, no grid nor values are shown. However, the chart shown in design mode does show all three labels on the first and only legend and all three lines.

Comment: What's that value of chartType?

Comment: Tried several types like FastLine, Column, Line but none of the data points or grids are displayed at any given time with any chart type I tried.

Comment: @JimSimson edited and added picture of run-time example, picture talks more than words.